# phpMyAdmin loading incredibly slow through nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, reverse-proxy, phpmyadmin

So I have a Synology NAS at home with some services running that I need to be accessible from the WWW, but understandably do not want to open ports on my home IP to the wide internet (especially because external services need to access my server on port 443) - so I decided to spin up an Always Free instance (0.48Gbps connectivity, 1 CPU, 1GB RAM) on Oracle Cloud with Ubuntu 22.04 installed and install nginx on it, to access these services from outside my home network. Then, I opened up the port on my router only to the IP address of the cloud instance.

I do have experience managing Linux servers via SSH, but this is my first time playing around with nginx in general, let alone reverse proxies.

During testing, I left the port open to all IPs, so I can test incoming traffic to my lab both directly, and via reverse proxy. Here´s where I´m starting to struggle:

- when I access phpMyAdmin running on the upstream server directly (I just query https://pma.upstream.mydomain.xyz:openedPort in my browser), it loads instantly - even with cache cleared out
- when I access phpMyAdmin running on the upstream server via the reverse proxy (by querying https://pma.reverseproxy.mydomain.xyz:443 in my browser), it takes over a minute to load after clearing browser cache. When cache is already loaded, it is not as slow (maybe 10s), but it is still much slower than querying the upstream server directly (which will not be possible when I close the port to wider internet). Having checked the browser console, what takes longest are tiny PNGs that phpMyAdmin uses as icons (each image is couple hundred bytes max) and larger CSS/JS files (couple 10s of KB).

When I access a different site on the upstream server via reverse proxy, I don´t seem to be having these problems, although it is true it is not serving that many tiny JS and PNG files, mostly just text

Below is my nginx server block config. Does anyone have any clue where I might be going wrong? Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name pma.reverseproxy.mydomain.xyz;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/reverseproxy.mydomain.xyz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/reverseproxy.mydomain.xyz/privkey.pem;

    resolver 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
    set $backend_server https://pma.upstream.mydomain.xyz:openedPort;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $backend_server;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Host pma.upstream.mydomain.xyz;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 8 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        proxy_read_timeout 20s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Serverfault is not for home but for information systems in a business environment